# How can I import an angular.js module into an angular application?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular

**Objective**: I would like to include the following carousel [example](https://theta-carousel.com/carousel-example.html#example=ellipse) into an Angular 2+ component.

The steps to include this carousel involve importing a 'theta' module. I'm not sure how this would work with Angular 2+ dependency injection. The directions mentioned in the following link apply to an AngularJs application: https://theta-carousel.com/api.html#add-to-angularjs-app

[image]

How could this be used in an Angular 2+ application?

Comment: do not include angularjs module - include it as a simple external js (jquery plugin) and thats it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to incorporate an AngularJs external package within an Angular package.

1. Use it as a jQuery plugin. This will require jQuery as well that can be included in the angular.json file:

   ```
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "src/assets/js/theta-carousel.min.js"
        ]
   ```

component file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any;


export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

ngOnInit(): void {
$('.example').theta_carousel({*/options*/})
```

2. Create a hybrid angularJs/angular application (not ideal, nor is it reccomended).

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use external source code in Angular2+ unless there is an NPM package for it, which I think is not available for theta-carousel. You will have to find other ways to have your own implementation for a carousel.

To start with, maybe you can check this [well-articulated article](https://netbasal.com/building-a-simple-carousel-component-with-angular-3a94092b7080).

Comment: I don't believe that's necessarily true. You can use a hybrid application approach (similar to how angularjs to angular migration works), which isn't ideal, but still an option at this point.